# Поменять местами caps и lctrl

Tags: клавиатура

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать следующие:

1. Поменять местами caps и ctrl;
2. Настроить переключалку - Caps на us и Shift + Caps на ru
3. Подсвечивать лампочку Scroll Lock на английской раскладке.

Вот мой конфиг, который я скармливаю xkbcomp:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   {
        // include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(shift_caps_switch)"

        replace key <CAPS> { [ Control_L ] };
        replace key <LCTL> { [ Caps_Lock ] };
        include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(shift_caps_switch)"

    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Беда в том, что все сразу не дается - или меняются кнопки, или настраивается переключение раскладок. Как быть?

Comment: второй и третий (под)вопросы лучше задать отдельными вопросами. т.к. они друг с другом никак не связаны.

Comment: кстати, по второму (под)вопросу рекомендую глянуть мою статью «заметки на полях клавиатуры» и [тему с её обсуждением](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=49203). то ли в «заметках», то ли в комментариях практически такая настройка, вроде бы, «пробегала».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Поменять местами caps и lctrl

поменяйте местами *keycodes* для этих двух клавиш:

```
$ xkbcomp $DISPLAY - | grep -m 2 'LCTL\|CAPS'
    <LCTL> = 37;
    <CAPS> = 66;
```

и всё остальное настраивайте исходя из того, что кнопка с надписью `caps` — 
это тепель `<LCTL>`, а левая кнопка с надписью `control` — это теперь `<CAPS>`.

---

менять можете «на лету», сохранив вывод приведённой команды в файл:

```
$ xkbcomp $DISPLAY файл
```

отредактировав его, и «загрузив» обратно симметричной командой:

```
$ xkbcomp файл $DISPLAY
```

**или** «стационарно», подправив используемый файл с *keycodes*. «найти» его не сложно, опираясь на приведённую вами информацию:

```
xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
```

файл называется `evdev`, находится (по умолчанию) в каталоге `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes`.

к слову, `aliases(qwerty)` «расшифровывается» как: файл `aliases` (в том же каталоге), а в нём секция `qwerty`.